# What's better than »More ...« as a main navigation tab?

Tags: navigation

I am looking for a solution for the following problem: We have a horizontal main navigation showing some of the most important topics covered by the website and a tab called "**All Topics**". So far so good, but we like to show another tab containing further navigational items . We do not want to call it "**More ...**" because it does not make sense calling it like this after already having the option "All Topics":

[image: wireframe example]

Any ideas how to name the last tab? It contains items "Videos", "Popular Posts", "FAQ", "Community".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Discover more
2. Rest
3. Expand
4. On the edge

hmm.... I just thought these in a minute....

Comment: This is really just different words, can you provide some explanation as to *why* these are more suitable than 'more'?

Comment: @anilkumble789 Thanks, I like "Discover more". I think we will try that.

Comment: @JonW We want to avoid the term "More" because during usability tests it confused users: They were wondering what more is to come after having the tab before named "All Topics".

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that your solution is fine.

Your site revolves around providing content on a set of topics. The most popular topics a user can visit have their dedicated tab, the rest of the topics are however displayed in another tab where all topics are listed.

The rest of the site; *Contact*, *FAQ*, *About* etc, that isn't part of a topic must be accessible also though. Having a dropdown labelled *More* is fine for this, showing content that can't be ordered in any of the topics.

However, if you still want to change it I would suggest *Other* -- Cueing that there is content that differs from the main content.